# Can `cal` show other Gregorian adoptions?

Tags: date, time, timezone, calendar, cal

On my host I can show the [adoption of the Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar) as it occurred for [Great Britain and its colonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar#Great_Britain_and_its_colonies) in 1752:

```
$ cal september 1752
   September 1752     
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2 14 15 16  
17 18 19 20 21 22 23  
24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

The corresponding adoption for [Denmark and Norway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar#Denmark_and_Norway) happened much earlier:

> Sunday, 18 February 1700, was followed by Monday, 1 March 1700.

I thought I could override the timezone environment variable to show this, but that doesn't work:

```
$ TZ=DK february 1700
   February 1700      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
             1  2  3  
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10  
11 12 13 14 15 16 17  
18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
25 26 27 28 29
```

How do I get `cal` to show Denmark's adoption of the Gregorian calendar?

My `cal` is supplied by [`bsdmainutils`](https://salsa.debian.org/meskes/bsdmainutils) version 11.1.2.

Comment: [That it be 1752 is actually a POSIX requirement](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cal.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cal` follows [the POSIX specification for `cal`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cal.html), which says

> as though the Gregorian calendar had been adopted on September 14, 1752.

There’s no option to show the calendar with a different switch date.

`ncal` supports different switch dates with the `-s` option:

```
$ ncal -s DK february 1700
    February 1700
Mo     5 12
Tu     6 13
We     7 14
Th  1  8 15
Fr  2  9 16
Sa  3 10 17
Su  4 11 18
```